# How laravel service provider and container work for each other?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-service-container

I have a confusion in the Laravel service Provider and Laravel container. In Laravel, how do service providers and containers work? Please give me a suitable example on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Service Container and Service Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018582/laravel-service-container-and-service-provider)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read the official documentation:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container