# Laravel Service Container and Service Provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-service-container

Need to understand Laravel service container and service provider through an example.

Answer (score 17):

The **Service container** is the place our application `bindings` are stored. And **service providers** are the classes where we register our bindings to the **service container**. In older releases of Laravel, we didn't have these providers and developers were always asking where to put the bindings. And the answer was confusing: "Where it makes the most sense."(!) Then, Laravel introduced these **service providers** and the *Providers* directory to make things more consistent.

Here is a basic example:

```
interface AcmeInterface {
    public function sayHi();
}

class AcmeImplementation implements AcmeInterface {
    public function sayHi() {
        echo 'Hi!';
    }
}

// Service Container
$app = new \Illuminate\Database\Container;

// Some required stuff that are also service providing lines 
// for app config and app itself.

$app->singleton('app', 'Illuminate\Container\Container');
$app->singleton('config', 'Illuminate\Config\Repository');

// Our Example Service Provider
$app->bind(AcmeInterface::class, AcmeImplementation::class);

// Example Usage:
$implementation = $app->make(AcmeInterface::class);
$implementation->sayHi();
```

As you can see:

- first, we create the container (in real life, Laravel does this for us inside `bootstrap/app.php`),
- then, we register our service (inside our **Service Provider** classes, and `config/app.php`),
- and finally, we get and use our registered service. (inside controllers, models, services, etc.)

Answer (score 11):

> **Service container** is where your services are registered.
>
> **Service providers** provide services by adding them to the container.

By reference of **Laracast**. Watch out to get understand.

**Service container**: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/24

**Service providers**: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/25